# How to only get new data without existing data from a Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a node in Firebase getting continually updated with information from a logfile. The node is `lines/` and each child of `lines/` is from a `post()` so it has a unique ID.

When a client first loads, I want to be able to grab the last `X` number of entries. I expect I'll do this with `once()`. From then on, however, I want to use an `on()` with `child_added` so that I get all new data. However, `child_added` gets *all* data stored in the Firebase and, after the initial setup, only want the new stuff.

I see that I can add a `limitToLast()` on the `on()`, but, if I say `limitToLast(1)` and a flood of entries come in, will my app still get all the new entries? Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, would you mind marking it as the solution? If not let me know what else is needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You need to include a `timestamp` property and run a query.**

```
// Get the current timestamp
var now = new Date().getTime();
// Create a query that orders by the timestamp
var query = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(now);
// Listen for the new children added from that point in time
query.on('child_added', function (snap) { 
  console.log(snap.val()
});

// When you add this new item it will fire off the query above
ref.push({ 
  title: "hello", 
  timestamp: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP 
});
```

The Firebase SDK has methods for ordering, `orderByChild()` and methods for creating a range `startAt()`. When you combine the two you can limit what comes back from Firebase.

Comment: The problem in your solution is the `new Date().getTime()` may not get the right timestamp if the client device is not be synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem in @David East's solution. He is using the local timestamp which may cause problem if the time is not accurate in client device. Here is my suggested solution (iOS Swift):

- Using `observeSingleEvent` to get the complete data set
- Then returned it in reversed order by `reversed()`
- Get the last timestamp by for example `data[0].timestamp`
- Using `queryStarting` for timestamp

  ```
   self._dbref.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryStarting(atValue: timestamp+1)
       .observe(.childAdded, with: {
          snapshot in
          print(snapshot.value)
    })
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. `child_added` should be called only for the new nodes. Without source code it's hard to tell why you get all the data in your `child_added` event.

You can check the chat demo app to see how they load new chat messages. The use case sounds similar.

https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/src/js/firechat.js#L347

Comment: The `child_added` event fires off for all data and *then* the new nodes. So he'll need to use a combination of a timestamp and a query to get only the latest nodes after a point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's  temporary but quick solution:

```
// define a boolean
var bool = false;

// fetch the last child nodes from firebase database
ref.limitToLast(1).on("child_added", function(snap) {
    if (bool) {
        // all the existing child nodes are restricted to enter this area
        doSomething(snap.val())
    } else {
        // set the boolean true to doSomething with newly added child nodes
        bool = true;
    }
});
```

**Disadvantage:** It will load all the child nodes.

**Advantage:** It will not process existing child nodes but just the newly added child nodes.

`limitToLast(1)` will do the work.