# Firebase: Get New Child Added

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When my application starts I do an initial fetch to Firebase to pull down all my data. When I later add data to my Firebase, I only want it to get the new child that's been added.

I'm currently achieving this like this. Is there a better way, or a built in way to do this in Firebase?

```
let initialFetch = false;

ref.once('value', snap => {
  // get all child data
  initialFetch = true;  
});

ref.on('child_added', (snap) => {
  if (!initialFetch) return;
  // get new child data
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1. If you need both new data and subsequent data, use `child_added`. It will fire immediately for all existing children and subsequently for any child that is added.
2. if you only want new data, add a timestamp to your children and `ref.orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(Date.now())`
3. If you need both new data and subsequent data, but want to treat the initial children differently: use `child_added` **and** `value` as you do now.

Also see: [How to only get new data without existing data from a Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885059/how-to-only-get-new-data-without-existing-data-from-a-firebase)

Comment: I'd love to use option 1 (`child_added`), but I need to fetch some more metadata from another api once I get back my initial data from Firebase. Does `.on()` support promises?

Comment: A promise can only resolve once. Firebase's `on()` will trigger every time the relevant event occurs, so cannot return a promise. If you only care about a single value, use `once()` (which returns a promise).