# How to retrieve all the data from firebase posted on current date

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a social media app in which user posts data on firebase, now I want to retrieve all the data from firebase that was posted on current date, below is my firebase database structure

[image]

I'm posting the timerstamp too, but I don't know how to retrieve the data according to the current date.

This is my code segment for getting timerstamp value but I'm unable to get the value:

```
mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles");
    mQuery=mDatabase.orderByChild("timerstamp").startAt(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

but ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is red underlined, and when I typecast it to string the query is getting null.

Comment: `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is a placeholder/marker that is replaced by the actual timestamp on **write** operations. You cannot use it to filter in queries, since those are a *read* operation.

Comment: so what should i do if i want to retrieve all the data posted on current date?

Comment: If you want to get the items after *now*, passing the current timestamp into `startAt` is a good approximation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885059/how-to-only-get-new-data-without-existing-data-from-a-firebase/33885787#33885787 for a JavaScript example or use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: does start at takes value as integer or string? for comparing?

Comment: It takes a value of the type you're comparing against. So in your case that would be a number.

Comment: i'm using this now:
`tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles");
        mQuery=mDatabase.orderByChild("timerstamp").startAt(tsLong);`

but still no success

Comment: ok so what should i do if i want the timestamp of current date excluding the time?

Comment: Create a range query starting at the day at `0:00` and ending at `23:59:59`. https://www.google.com/search?q=java+timestamp+of+current+date+excluding+the+time